# Magento Aheadworks Automatic Product Callouts doesn't show on website

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

I've installed the AheadWorks' Automatic Product Callouts extension for Magento. I've followed the steps on their website on how to install this extension and everything is set up and installed correctly. The problem is when I call the block nothing shows on the website.

Installation Guide:
http://confluence.aheadworks.com/display/EUDOC/Automatic+Product+Callouts

This is the code I use to call the block on my page:

```
{{block type="automaticcallouts/automaticcallouts" block_type="best_selling"}}
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

So after countless hours of struggling I finally found what was preventing multiple functionality problems (including my initial question's problem) on the Magento website... The answer, an outdated Fishpig (wordpress integration) extension.

After I read the error logs I found that Fishpig was the problem, but didn't know what the exact problem was. I then saw that my version of Fishpig was way outdated and I simply just downloaded and installed the new version and everything was working again.